# How to get SVG dimentions to scale with screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've tried changing between `<line>` and `<path>` in case the percentage parameters made a difference. But I'm still getting the same issue where the `<svg>` won't line up with my `<img>`'s. My end goal is to basically have the 2 ends of the `<svg>` lock into the border of the `<img>`'s. Any advice would be amazing.

[Pen](https://codepen.io/chriskaram/pen/QOgaeK)

[html](/questions/tagged/html):

```
<div class="svg-benefitsContainer">
<svg class="benefitSVG" height="500%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <line class="benefitSVG1" x1="15%" y1="15%" x2="20%" y2="32%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/5a09f06d9140b7f3b7d84274/1510600813361/quality.png" class="benefitsImgMed" />
<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/5a09f014ec212d1131cf09fc/1510600724150/flash.png" class="benefitsImgLig" />
```

[css](/questions/tagged/css):

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.benefitsImgMed,
.benefitsImgLig,
.benefitsImgArr,
.benefitsImgNig {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
}

.benefitsImgMed {
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  width: 13%;
}

.benefitsImgLig {
  margin-top: 32%;
  margin-left: 19%;
  width: 13%;
}

.benefitsImgArr {
  margin-left: 37%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  width: 13%;
}

.benefitsImgNig {
  margin-left: 66%;
  margin-top: 18%;
  width: 13%;
}

.svg-benefitsContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500%;
}

.benefitSVG {
  position: absolute
}

.benefitSVG1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 5;
  /*L 125 315 q -20 200 115 190*/
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? It should be a part of your answer, not offsite. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies. Added the code I have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because SVG percentages work differently to HTML percentages.

- The `<svg>` `width` and `height` are relative to its parent container width and height respectively.
- The `<line>` `x` and `width` are relative to the SVG viewport width.
- The `<line>` `y` and `height` are relative to the SVG viewport height.
- The `<image>` `left` and `top` are relative to the browser width.

If you want it to be reliable, the safest solution is to put all of the objects in an SVG file together.  It's a lot simpler to understand also.

```css
body{background-color:black;}

line, circle {
  fill: black;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-benefitsContainer">
<svg class="benefitSVG" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <line class="benefitSVG1" x1="14.5" y1="12.5" x2="25.5" y2="38.5" />

  <circle cx="14.5" cy="12.5" r="8"/>
  <image xlink:href="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/5a09f06d9140b7f3b7d84274/1510600813361/quality.png"
       x="8" y="6" width="13" height="13"
       class="benefitsImgMed"/>

  <circle cx="25.5" cy="38.5" r="8"/>
  <image xlink:href="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/5a09f014ec212d1131cf09fc/1510600724150/flash.png"
       x="19" y="32" width="13" height="13"
       class="benefitsImgLig"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I managed to create a workaround but yours is much cleaner and proper coding etiquette. I had to go through it a few times, first time I get into SVG and it's quite a handful lol. That's really useful, thank you!